# C# Mongodb Deserialize List of BsonDocument types to List of Class Types

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to deserialize a List of BsonDocuments to class Type using BsonSerializer but I am getting an error "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'". It only works for a single BsonDocument Type.

How do I Deserialize a BsonDocument list to list class type?

```
        var projection = Builders<Property>.Projection
            .Include(x => x.Type);

        var values= await MongoCollection
                                .Find(Builders<Property>.Filter.Empty)
                                .Project(projection)
                                .ToListAsync()
                                .ConfigureAwait(false);

        var test = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Property>>(values);
```

Comment: this link maybe help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768516/how-to-convert-listbsondocument-to-listclass-in-c-sharp, you could use collection with type in your code I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, a dumb way to achieve it via `foreach`.

```cs
var list = new List<Property>();
foreach (var item in values) {
    var model = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Property>(item);
    list.Add(model);
}
```